# When sending php variable in a href body i cant access variable in new page

Tags: php, email

I have this code

```
$sucess_image = 'http://www.test.gr/images/message.jpg';
$body         = "<a href=\"http://test.gr/print.php?orderid=\"{$orderId}\"><img src='$sucess_image' /></a>";
$from         = "<test@test.gr>";
$to           = "<$email>";
$subject      = 'test';
$newsubject   = '=?ISO-8859-7?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
$host         = "test.gr";
$username     = "info@test.gr";
$password     = "xxx";
$headers      = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0"\r\n"',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8"\r\n"',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' => 'base64',
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Cc' => $cc,
    'Subject' => $newsubject
);
$smtp         = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
));
$mail         = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

in test.gr/print.php the orderid is empty, the problem is that this variable has value when i send it to email, is there any problem in code and i cant pass the variable?

Comment: mind formatting your code? It's extremely hard to read.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to format it

Comment: formatted it for you

Comment: `send($to, $headers, $body)` - headers usually goes last. Syntax is: "to, subject, message, headers". `var_dump($body);` reveals what? and what's the value of `$orderId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is malformed -

```
 $body ="<a href=\"http://test.gr/print.php?orderid={$orderId}\"><img src='$sucess_image' /></a>";
```

Replace yours with this - and watch your quotes!

Personally i find it easier to use singles quote instead of double quotes inside variables - like:

```
$body ="<a href='http://test.gr/print.php?orderid=".$orderId."'><img src='".$sucess_image."' /></a>";
```

but its down to person taste...  but you may find it easier to!

I'm not sure - i could be wrong... but try removing:

```
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' => 'base64',
```

Comment: if i do this i have this problem : http://www.test.gr/print.php?orderid4329 insted of http://www.test.gr/print.php?orderid=34329 . this means i lost this symbol "=" and the first digit of the number "3"

Comment: Then you have another issue somewhere else!